# How to parse Html File and read the elements of it?

Tags: ios4

Please suggest how to parse an HTML file?

Comment: Not with Regex http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/694652

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at NSXMLParser. With XML you can invent your own tags but it should be able to parse HTML as well